What was that old movie where the guy got turned into a stone statue
I need help to identify a movie I saw when I was 4 year old (1984) - the movie is older. I saw this movie where at the end (that's all I remember), there's this guy who got turned to stone (earlier in the movie) got back to life when this girl dropped her tears on him (i think). I'm not sure if it's tears or some sort of magic potion. I also think they are lovers? I got this scene stuck in me until today.. so I'm curious to find out this movie and compare it to my memory :P It's a real life movie, not animation. It's also not a comedy.
I think the scene where she turned him back to human was indoor. Like he was a status standing close to stairs? They were inside a big mansion? The scene was pretty dramatic.
UPDATE: More info: it's probably not a Hollywood more, maybe a Russian movie. Pretty sure it was from Europe.

Forgot to mention that I saw this movie in Asia, and we usually watch foreign European movies.. so it might not be a Hollywood movie, but it could

Swiss Army Tears....Taken for Granite....suffice it to say, a very common theme. More detail might be needed here.

I guess you watched the movie in Vietnam. Do you remember anything about its Vietnamese name? (I'm a fellow Vietnamese).

Yes I watched it in Vietnam. I have no idea what the name was, or who the actors were. I don't even remember if it was black and white or color.

I remember around that period (1983-84), I was watching the TV series "Maika" too. Oh, it might be a Russian movie?

If you were really only four when you saw it, it's pretty unlikely that you're remembering it correctly in the first place. Was a parent around watching it with you that you could ask about it?

I'm gonna try to ask my parents about it and will get back. What I am really sure about is that the guy is turned to stone, and it was a drop of water/tear that brought him back to life.

Can you remember setting? Modern day(ish), or ancient greece-like, fantasy/real world, etc?

@TrishLing It's certainly not in a fantasy world like Wizard of Oz (there's no animals, people flying and such). It's real world with fantasy elements (a curse that turns people to stone statues). It wasn't modern, people don't wear trench coat, shirt and ties, it felt more like ancient greek period.

The movie Clash of the Titans (1981) features a monster named Medusa who turns at least one character to stone by making eye contact with him:

Then she is killed by a guy who takes her head outside her lair, and holds it up in the air while standing on what could be stairs:


OP said the scene he remembers was of someone turning back into a human from stone, not turning into stone.

Yeah, saw that. Thing is OP memories are often inaccurate, especially when they're from 30 years ago, when OP was 4 years old. My theory is "post the answer in case it happens to be right." Doesn't cost anyone anything, does it?

Thanks Shiz Z. for trying :) I appreciate it. CofT (1981) seems like a cool movie, I might end up watching it :) TrishLing you are right, the person got turned to a stone statue somewhere in the movie, then at the end, he got saved and turned back to human by this girl.

Try "A simple wish" I had the exact same scene stuck in my head for the longest today and it turned out to be this movie! Hopefully you find it soon ☺️

Hi. A simple wish is released in 1997, which is way after 1982-1984 :)
